# Slideshow using CrossSlide

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Sorry for such a basic question, but I can't seem to get the CrossSlide jquery Plugin to work.

I want to make simple slideshow with different imags that are centered in the webbrowser and do not all have the same dimensions.

thanks!

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<style type="text/css">

body {

    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
    color: white;
}



a {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}

#slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>


<title>CrossSlide</title>


</head>



<body>


<div><span class="contact-info"><a href="mailto:none@none.com">none@none.com</a></div>


<div id="slideshow"></div>






<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cross-slide.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#slideshow').crossSlide({
      sleep: 2,
      fade: 1
    }, [
      { src: 'data/tea.jpg' },
      { src: 'data/tea2.jpg' },
    ])
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The big problem was that you had a old jQuery library referenced.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cross-slide.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#slideshow').crossSlide({
            sleep: 2,
            fade: 1
        }, [
                { src: 'content/tea.png' },
                { src: 'content/tea2.jpg' }
            ]);
    });
</script>
```

If you are using Chrome you could click the wrench icon (top right), then "Tools", then "JavaScript Console", or use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+J, then you would see the javascript error message.

Comment: works for me in Chrome, IE9, Firefox 14. are you using a old version of cross slide also? I tested with: https://raw.github.com/tobia/CrossSlide/master/jquery.cross-slide.js and it worked. What error message do you get?

Comment: It just isn't showing any pictures. I am not at all experienced with jquery, I imagine something else is stated wrong?

Comment: for some reason the jquery wouldn't load from google. But what caused the real problem was that when using CrossSlide, it seems you can't set width and height of the #slideshow div to 100%. which is pretty much what I wanted - to fill the whole screen. Also the images are cutoff, what I wanted is the images to scale to the #slideshow element (ie. the whole screen, since I wanted to set it to 100%)